# Jquery Validation Watermark

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, watermark

I am using jQuery validation plugin and [Watermark plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/).  The problem I am facing is when i applied a watermark to any input field for which validation is also applied then validations are failing

For Example:

```
<input type=text name=myinput class="required">
```

and I applied a watermark for this field in document ready function:

```
$("#myinput ").Watermark("myinput ");
```

This is the sample case where validation is failing as `value=myinput` is set for input field which is watermarked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for this by registering a method for validation rules and using that along with the class for that input tag like

```
$.validator.addMethod("watermark", Watermark, $.validator.messages["required"]);

function Watermark(value, element) {
            if (element.className.match("required") != null) {
                var id = "WM_" + element.name;
                return value != document.getElementById(id).value;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
```

And for input tag use this

```
<input type='text' class='required watermark'>
```